# Hibernate tries to make many2many link twice (concurrency)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a class that has a many-to-many connection to itself.

In the problem scenario, I have two objects:
Item 1
Item 2

They are both being connected to each other. However, here's the twist: the UI sends two simultaneous requests for object update: one for item 1, one for item 2. **So this is a concurrency issue.**

The problem:
Function for updating detects that Item 1 is not yet linked to Item 2 and establishes the link. This results in an insert into the many2many table (Item 1, Item 2)
Function for updating also detects that Item 2 is not yet linked to Item 1 and establishes the link. This results in the same insert into many2many table (Item 1, Item 2)

One of these two inserts will fail with

```
Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.ItemLinks' with unique index 'IX_ItemLinks_1'. The duplicate key value is (1, 2).
```

I tried putting the update method into

```
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

But this has no effect.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you modify the client that it does not fire the second request?

Comment: Yes I can (and did), but I'd like to SOLVE the issue, not AVOID it.

Answer (score 0):

`@Transactional` annotation alone cannot solve your problem. Somewhere inside your update method you have to check if `Item1` is already linked to `Item2`.

Together with `@Transactional` it will help to eliminate your problem.

Comment: I DO already check for that. It is not seen however. I think objects are read from cache ant that's why they have the old state and are not locked.

Comment: have you tried flushing the entities to the DB after the update method?